# Algorithm for computing the collection of all string homomorphisms $f$ such that $f(s) = t$ for fixed strings $s,t$

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, formal-languages, programming, semigroup-homomorphism

I'm coding on a website in Django so all my code will be implemetned in Python.

Anyway, I'm interested in the most efficient algorithm to compute the following problem.

Given input strings $s = abcdAbcdBCe$  and $t = xyz\dots \alpha$ where capital leters are variable symbols (!) and lower case letters are any characters in the string's alphabet; enumerate the collection of all string homomorphisms $f : \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ such that $f(s) = t$.  If there are none, then return an empty set.

**Attempt.**

(TODO: I'm writing this now in Python code)

**EDIT:** $AB = A\circ B$ always in my application, or in other words juxtaposition actually is not possible internally (of two variables). I noticed that this usually greatly simplifies the possible number of string homs to enumerate.

Comment: I'd suggest working out the answers for cases with very short inputs for $s$ and $t$, first without and then with variables involved.

Comment: I think what you want is just variable to variable (only) subtitution (I've spoken with Dev directly).  In which case there is either a match or there isn't one, and when there's a match there is only one possible variable mapping.

Comment: Please clarify your question by giving an example.